# Defining constants in C

Tags: c++, c

I was working with C++ for a long time and now I am on a C project.
I am in the process of converting a C++ program to C.

I am having difficulty with the constants used in the program.
In the C++ code we have constants defined like

```
static const int X = 5 + 3;
static const int Y = (X + 10) * 5
static const int Z = ((Y + 8) + 0xfff) & ~0xfff
```

In C, these definitions throw error.
When I use #defines instead of the constants like

```
#define X (5+3);
#define Y (((X) + 10) * 5)
#define Z ((((Y) + 8) + 0xfff) & ~0xfff)
```

the C compiler complains about the definitions of "Y" and "Z".

Could anyone please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: People have already given the solution - but I just want to point out the reason why you need to remove the semicolon. `#define` in c causes the preprocessor to do a textual substitution before compilation, so imagine taking the contents of X and plugging it into Y and you will likely see what the problem is.

Comment: Some people also use enums to declare constants in C, e.g. `enum { N = 100 };`.

Comment: `static` is redundant in the C++ example. `const` objects that are not explicitly declared `extern` have internal linkage anyway.

Comment: Yes it was the semicolon. Silly me. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the semi-colon from the #define X line

```
#define X (5+3)
#define Y (((X) + 10) * 5)
#define Z ((((Y) + 8) + 0xfff) & ~0xfff)
```

Answer (score 3):

`#define X (5+3);` is wrong, it needs to be `#define X (5+3)` (without ';')

also be aware of the difference between using static const and #define: in static const, the value is actually evaluated, in #define, it's pre-processor command, so

```
#define n very_heavy_calc()
...
n*n;
```

will result in evaluating very_heavy_calc() twice

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an enum:

```
enum {
  X = 5 + 3,
  Y = (X + 10) * 5,
  Z = ((Y + 8) + 0xfff) & ~0xfff
};
```